# How to query a document within a document in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

OK so I have this document structure within my database:

```
Message: {
    uid: "id",
    subject: "I AM A MESSAGE!",
    body: "ASDF",
    recipients: {
        name: "John Doe",
        hasRead: "true"
    }
}
```

How do I use the C# driver to write a query for items that only John Doe has received? I'm using the MongoDB driver v1.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, the query would be

```
db.Message.find({"recipients.name" : "John Doe"});
```

The C# query depends on the data structure you're using in C#. I'm irritated that `recipients` is plural, but the json is not an array. Since there are different ways of mapping C# collections to JSON, I can't present the C# query in linq form.

However, given the data structure you posted, this should work:

```
db.GetCollection("Message").Find(Query.EQ("recipients.name", "John Doe"));
```

Comment: Thanks! The end query is exactly how I ended up doing it. The reason `recipients` is plural is that it's supposed to be a list, each element having a `name` and `hasRead` property. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in my example. Thanks for your answer!